# How to concatenate [Maybe Text] with lenses?

Tags: haskell, lenses

Is there any way to write the following with lenses...

```
[Maybe Text] -> Text
```

...which can probably be generalised to:

```
(Monoid a, Traversable t) => t a -> a
```

A concrete example of what I'm trying to do:

```
[Just "abc", Nothing, Just "def"] -> "abcdef"
[Nothing, Nothing] -> ""
```

PS: I'm *assuming* that lenses have some funky combinator to do this. If I'm being blindsided by the awesomeness of lenses, and this is achieved easily by a simpler combinator, please let me know.

Comment: Isn't your generalized from not a generalization of `[Maybe Text] -> Maybe Text`?

Comment: No, its actually `[Maybe Text] - > Text` which should default to `""` (empty string) for the edge-case.

Comment: but your `(Monoid a, Traversable t) => t a -> a` hints that you get a `Traversable` of `a`s (so `Maybe b`s), and thus if `a ~ Maybe b`, then it will thus return an `a` hence `Maybe b`.

Comment: I think my generalisation is wrong, in that case. The examples are the actual behaviour I want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `(Monoid a, Traversable t) => t a -> a` function can be generalized further to a simple [**`fold :: (Foldable f, Monoid a) => f a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:fold).

For example:

```
Prelude> import Data.Foldable
Prelude Data.Foldable> fold [Just "abc", Nothing, Just "def"]
Just "abcdef"
```

We can unwrap it out of the `Maybe` with:

```
import Data.Foldable(fold, mempty)
import Data.Maybe(maybe)

foldMaybe :: (Foldable f, Monoid a) => f (Maybe a) -> a
foldMaybe = fromMaybe mempty . fold
```

For example:

```
Prelude Data.Foldable Data.Maybe> foldMaybe [Just "abc", Nothing, Just "def"]
"abcdef"
Prelude Data.Foldable Data.Maybe> foldMaybe [Nothing] :: String
""
```

Comment: wow - I never realised that `Maybe`'s monoid instance behaves this way - `Just "abc" <> Just "def" == Just "abcdef"`

Comment: This is a fine answer, but just for kicks, I'll wait to see if someone can come up with a solution with a lenses.

Comment: @SaurabhNanda: Yes `Maybe a` is an instance of `Monoid` *given `a` is an instance of `Monoid`. It will map a `Nothing <> Just x == Just x <> Nothing == Just x`, and `Just x <> Just y == Just (x <> y)`.

Comment: I don't know why I was expecting `<>` to behave like `<|>` in the case of `Maybe`

Answer (score 7):

As a variant to Willem's solution, I prefer a double `fold` (one for the list, another for the `Maybe`):

```
> fold . fold $ [Just "abc", Nothing, Just "def"]
"abcdef"
```

In fact, `fold = maybe mempty id = fromMaybe mempty` for `Maybe`, so it's really the same.

Its general type is:

```
fold . fold :: (Monoid a, Foldable t1, Foldable t2, Monoid (t1 a)) => t2 (t1 a) -> a
```

which perfectly applies to `[Maybe a]`.

---

Another nice solution, suggested below by @dfeuer:

```
foldMap fold
```

Here, `fold` removes the `Just` wrappers while replacing `Nothing`s with empty strings. Then, `foldMap` concatenates all the resulting strings.

Comment: Better, I think: `foldMap fold`.

Comment: @dfeuer Agreed. Added.

Comment: If `p` is a monoid morphism, then we should have `p . foldMap f = foldMap (p . f)` (an unstated naturality law that Ed Kmett told me is guaranteed by parametricity). For `Maybe`, fold is indeed a monoid morphism. So fold @Maybe . foldMap f = foldMap (fold @Maybe . f). In this case, f = id.

Comment: Even better, `foldMap g` is generally a monoid morphism for `Maybe`, lists, and sequences, but not for sets or maps (even the "monoidal" style). I believe monoidal maps guarantee `foldMap g` is a commutative monoid morphism, but don't quote me on that.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is just a fold, so you can "use lenses" in a silly way using `foldOf`

```hs
foldOf :: Monoid a => Fold s a -> s -> a
```

so if you could find a `myFold :: Fold (t a) a`, you can use it with `foldOf` to get:

```hs
foldOf myFold :: Monoid a => t a -> a
```

Luckily for any instance of `Foldable t`, we have accesses to `folded :: Fold (t a) a`.  So we can use `foldOf` with `folded`:

```hs
foldOf :: Monoid a => Fold s a -> s -> a
folded :: Foldable t => Fold (t a) a

foldOf folded :: (Foldable t, Monoid a) => t a -> a
```